# What does final generated models with TM-score of DMPfold signify in "sequence.ema.txt" file?

Tags: protein-structure

So, my runs have finished and got 5 final models. I predicted TM-score of one model to understand the result. The output of "predict-tmscore.sh" for "final_1.pdb" is:

```
1 models read from PDB file
1 models read from PDB file
nres is 377
neff is 15423
dpscore is -300.599030
dpscorenorm is -0.082424
Probability of each TM-score bin (cols 1-10), estimated TM-score (col 11) and prob TM > 0.5 (col 12) written to sequence.ema.txt
Estimated TM-score of ../final_1.pdb is 0.5
```

could you please help me understand what does "nres", "neff", "dpscore", and "dpscorenorm" below mean:

```
    nres is 377 
neff is 15423 
dpscore is -300.599030 
dpscorenorm is    -0.082424
```

and it also generates a "sequence.ema.txt" file with below value:

```
2.0308916646172293e-05 2.0682286958617624e-06 0.04564645141363144 0.14857041835784912 0.27177685499191284 0.31814685463905334 0.19150513410568237 0.022412151098251343 0.001872337656095624 4.743059980683029e-05 0.5036169363265117 0.5339840054512024
```

Please let me know what these above values signify?

And,I would really appreciate your comments on what does "rawdistpred.1" file mean? There are total 9 such files. When predicitng TM-score, do I need to use "rawdistpred.1" file for all final models or I can use any "rawdistpred.*" file?

thanks!

Comment: Excellent question and answers on two core structure prediction programs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is described briefly in [the paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-019-11994-0). The four quantities are inputs to the estimator of model accuracy:

- `nres` is the sequence length.
- `neff` is an effective sequence count, or how deep the alignment was.
- `dpscore` is how well the final model matches the initial distance prediction.
- `dpscorenorm` is a normalised version of the above.

Don't worry too much about directly interpreting these. They are only given for completion. The important line is `Estimated TM-score of ../final_1.pdb is 0.5`, indicating that DMPfold just about thinks this is a decent model.

The "sequence.ema.txt" is more raw output giving the probability of the TM-score being in each bin. "rawdistpred.1" is the distance predictions from the first iteration. Always use "rawdistpred.1" as input to the TM-score predictor as this is how it was trained.